I need to resolve vue function to find soccer players by club
I need to get the players by club. When I select a club in the first dropdown, I see every player from the league, I want to see only players from the selected club:
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="topnav"></div>
    <div>
      <div class="clubDropdown">
        <label for="klub">Odaberi klub:</label>
        <select v-model="selectedKlub" >
          <option value="" disabled selected>Odaberi klub</option>
          <option v-for="klub in klubovi" :value="klub._id" :key="klub._id">{{ klub.naziv }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button @click="otvoriDialog">Dodaj igrača</button>
      
      <ModalComponent v-if="dialogOtvoren" @zatvori="zatvoriDialog">
        <AddPlayer @zatvori="zatvoriDialog" />
        <button @click="zatvoriDialog" class="close">X</button>
      </ModalComponent>
    </div>

    <div v-if="errorMessage" class="error-message">{{ errorMessage }}</div>

    <div class="grid">
      <div v-for="igrac in igraci" :key="igrac._id" @click="otvoriSliku(igrac)">
        <img :src="igrac.slika" alt="Slika igrača">
        <p>{{ igrac.ime }} {{ igrac.prezime }}</p>
        <h2>{{ igrac.nadimak }}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import AddPlayer from '../components/AddPlayer.vue';
import ModalComponent from '../components/ModalComponent.vue';

export default {
  name: 'PlayerView',
  components: {
    AddPlayer,
    ModalComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      klubovi: [],
      selectedKlub: '',
      igraci: [],
      dialogOtvoren: false,
      errorMessage: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async dobaviKlubove() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/klubovi');
        this.klubovi = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Greška prilikom dobavljanja klubova:', error);
        this.errorMessage = 'Došlo je do greške prilikom dobavljanja klubova sa servera.';
      }
    },
    async dobaviIgrace() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/igraci');
        this.igraci = response.data
      } catch(error) {
        console.error('Greška prilikom dobavljanja klubova:', error);
        this.errorMessage = 'Došlo je do greške prilikom dobavljanja klubova sa servera.';
      }
    },
    otvoriDialog() {
      this.dialogOtvoren = true;
    },
    zatvoriDialog() {
      this.dialogOtvoren = false;
    },
    otvoriSliku(igrac) {
      window.open(igrac.slika, '_blank');
    },
  },
  
  mounted() {
    this.dobaviKlubove();
    this.dobaviIgrace();
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
  .error-message {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); /* Promijenjeno sa repeat(3, 1fr) na repeat(5, 1fr) */
  gap: 20px;
}
.grid div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>


I tried a lot of methods, but every time I change club, the club list is blocked.
Here is a GitHub link for frontend:  https://github.com/HZHBKANJINA/nlhzhbfrontend
and for backend https://github.com/HZHBKANJINA/nlhzhbliga

Please provide data structure for the klubovi array.

You are defining selectedKlub but you are not using it. It should be either used to send for a new API call or to filter the data.
If you want to load API data once and filter them later you have to match the code to show only the items that are in the selectedKlub.
For example:
<div v-for="igrac in igraci" :key="igrac._id" @click="otvoriSliku(igrac)">
   <span v-if="igrac.klub == selectedKlub">
        <img :src="igrac.slika" alt="Slika igrača">
        <p>{{ igrac.ime }} {{ igrac.prezime }}</p>
        <h2>{{ igrac.nadimak }}</h2>
    </span>
</div>


Adding v-if="igrac.klub == selectedKlub" will show only the items where igrac.klub are equal to selectedKlub.
(You have to return from the API klub as well if you don't already)
